# How can I retrieve image in database to show in slideshow?

Tags: database, slideshow, slide

I have a table tbl_slide and field slide_id, slide_img, slide_name. I want to show all my images from table tbl_slide and show all image in database to show up. but I don't know why it don't work as my wish. Any help; I'll appreciate your help. thanks

```
 <ul>
        <?php
            $sql="select * from tbl_slide";
            $query=mysql_query($sql);
            while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
                echo "<li><img scr='images/slides/".$row['slide_img']."'
                 alt='1' title='".$row['slide_name']."' id='1' /></li>";
            }
        ?>

 <!--<li><img src="images/slides/111.png" alt="Envy & Elitepad" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/slides/333.png" alt="ePrinter & Hp touchsmart" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/slides/2222.png" alt="All in One & Folio" /></li>-->

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the page in a browser, right click on an image, and click View Image. What is the path in the address bar? Is it what you expected? If so, what are the URLs you're storing in the database table?

Comment: Ok now it work! but I have other problem is in the first id in database it don't show.

Comment: Can you check the source of the page and see if the problem is with the database record not being retrieved, or not being displayed correctly?